# How to have trailing dash to command (to allow command to consume stdin) in python sh

Tags: python, shell, sh

How do I approach converting this:
`echo -e 'FROM busybox\nRUN echo "hello world"' | docker build -`

into sh (https://github.com/amoffat/sh)  syntax.

The issue I have is that the args are tokenized and quoted. So docker isn't able to pass stdin onto the end of the command since - has single quotes placed around it. Digging in the docs I'm not seeing a way to support this.

Thanks for any help you can provide (alternatively if you have good examples of doing this in subprocess, that would work.)!

Comment: `-` isn’t special shell syntax. It should work fine as a normal argument. Did you try something involving it that didn’t work?

Comment: You should provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I have is that the args are tokenized and quoted. So docker isn't able to pass stdin onto the end of the command since - has single quotes placed around it.

Like I commented,

> `-` isn’t special shell syntax. It should work fine as a normal argument.

Still, here’s how it looks like you do it, going by the docs. Using [`_in`](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/special_arguments.html#in),

```py
dockerfile = r"""
FROM busybox
RUN echo "hello world"
"""

docker.build("-", _in=dockerfile)
```

Comment: Found the issue, I literally followed the docs which have a trailing space after the `-`.  My fault, I should have provided an example.